# Modifying Twitter Bootstrap Color Scheme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to modify the color scheme of a website I based off of this example: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

I successfully modified the background color of the entire page with

```
body{background-color:#XXXXXX}
```

This does not modify the background color of the div (grey in the page I linked to).  I believe the div is of subclass jumbotron (not sure if that's the right terminology), and I am having trouble modifying its background color.  I can modify the background color of things within the div (like a paragraph, for example), however I would like to change the entire background of the div.  I would also like to do the same thing with the navigation bar, however I think the two issues are closely related.  If you could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place for any web developer to start is the web console. Try right-clicking the element of the page that you're interested in and then clicking 'Inspect Element'. A console will be brought up that highlights the element you've selected. On the right, you'll see a box where composite CSS rules are listed. Use these rules to determine what is overriding the change you want to happen.

Comment: A slight expansion on this: I had to select the subclass in div that I wanted to modify (and then everything within that inherited the color).  In my example, I needed to modify div.jumbotron

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to develop a website using bootstrap is to use the inspector tool in your browser (usually opened with F12) and then you can pretty much see the classes within divs that you need to modify.

For navigation the class is commonly just **.nav**, and for the rest of the content, it's usually wrapped in **.well** div. Just seach out with the inspector and you will figure everything out the easy way!

Comment: And in addition to this, if something is not working, try to mark your CSS attribute with !important -tag. It's sometimes required to override the basic stylesheet in bootstrap's default.